# How to copy files from an old PC to a new PC?

Tags: windows, networking, hard-drive, sata, pata

I do apologize if this question has been brought up before. In that case, please refer me to the answer of that other question. I did search for answers but most of them seem to deal with migrations, like moving from operating system x to operating system y, or moving from an old computer to a new one but wanting to preserve all the programs, settings, bookmarks, et. al.

I have some files on an old PATA internal hard drive of an old PC that I would like to move over to a new PC. I think simple file and folder copy operation will do, but I am not sure how to approach this or what method to use to get the best results.

The old PC can only use PATA internal hard drives. So I can't just plug in an internal SATA hard drive and do a drag-and-drop from one to the other. The new PC has both PATA and SATA support. But since the PATA drive is a system disk I can't access the files.

The old PC has a DVD burner and I thought about using it to copy the files over one DVD at a time. But a DVD can only fit lite 4.3 GB. It's not enough, and requires several DVD discs.

The old PC doesn't even have a LAN port. However, I do have an Intel PCI network card that I might be able to use. The only other communications ports available is a COM port and an LPT port.

How do I get those files over to the new PC? What kind of transfer speeds can I expect if I use a serial cable between them? The new PC has a COM port. Or should I try to get that LAN card installed and hook them up P2P? Or should I mount the PATA drive inside the new PC and try getting ownership rights?

**Update**

---

I have decided to connect the two computers directly to each other using a crossover Ethernet cable. For that, I had to install a network card to the old computer. The card works as expected, i.e. I can use it to connect to Internet and surf the web.

Now the tricky part of getting the two computers to communicate to each other.

```
PC1 (the new computer)
IP 125.1.1.1
Subnet mask 255.255.255.0
Windows Vista

PC2
IP 125.1.1.2
Subnet mask 255.255.255.0
Windows XP
```

I tried pinging from XP to Vista and it worked. Four packets are sent and four packets are received. It works the other way around as well, from Vista to XP.

I can see the XP computer in Vista but I can't see the Vista computer in XP. Also, when I try to access the XP computer from Vista, I get a prompt asking for user name and password. I believe I am typing in the correct username and password but I can't get access. I even tried changing the password on the XP computer but to no avail. How can I disable password protection for network connections in XP?

Can someone please post an answer on how to establish a direct network connection between two Windows computers and how to configure them?

Comment: You say that the PATA is a system disk and so you can't access the files. But that doesn't follow. Can you explain why you think you can't access the files?

Comment: @Sammy It's a pesky permissions issue within Windows.  What version are you using?  I know I've overridden the permissions be forcing admin access and disabling a lot of Windows UAC stuff.  I've done it both by plugging the drive directly in and by using an external housing to plug it in via USB.

Answer (score 2):

Take ownership of the drive. Follow the steps below:

```
a.    Right-click on the drive. Choose Properties.
b.    Click the Security tab.
c.    Click the button Advanced.
d.    Click the button Edit.
e.    Double-click on one permission entry. 
f.    Give it full control right, and check the box 
      “Apply these permissions to objects and/or containers 
      within this container only”.
```

Refer the below links to know more about permission and access denied.

[How do I open a file if I get an access denied message?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows7/How-do-I-open-a-file-if-I-get-an-access-denied-message)

[What to know before applying permissions to a file or folder?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows7/What-to-know-before-applying-permissions-to-a-file-or-folder)

Also found a [blog post](http://www.blogsdna.com/2159/how-to-take-ownership-grant-permissions-to-access-files-folder-in-windows-7.htm) that has direction with screen captures if it helps.

**UPDATE FOR CROSSOVER CABLE QUESTION**

Answer from [Microsoft Support](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/connect-two-computers-using-a-crossover-cable):

### To connect two computers with a crossover cable

This works best if both computers are running this version of Windows.

1. Plug each end of the crossover cable into a network port on the back
   of each computer.
2. On one of the computers that is running this version of Windows, do
   the following:

   Open Network and Sharing Center by clicking the Start button Picture
   of the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Network and
   Internet, and then clicking Network and Sharing Center.
3. In the network map at the top of Network and Sharing Center,
   double-click the Unidentified network‍ icon. (If you have more than
   one network, this icon will be labeled Multiple networks.)
4. If network discovery and file sharing are turned off, in Network,
   click the Information bar containing the following message: "Network
   discovery and file sharing are turned off. Network computers and
   devices are not visible. Click to change...," and then click Turn on
   network discovery and file sharing.  Administrator permission
   required If you are prompted for an administrator password or
   confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
5. In the Network discovery and file sharing dialog box, select one of
   the following options:

   - No, make the network that I am connected to a private network
   - Yes, turn on network discovery and file sharing for all public
     networks

   The first option is usually the best choice because it only affects
   the network that you are connected to.

---

**Notes**

- Networks created with crossover cables are automatically set up as
  "Public place" networks, which means that network discovery, file
  sharing, and printer sharing are off by default.
- For Gigabit Ethernet or token ring networks, you will need a slightly
  different kind of crossover cable. For more information, contact a
  cable manufacturer.

---

Icons for both computers should now be visible in the Network window. Double-click each computer icon to share printers and other resources.

---

**Note**

If one of the computers is running Windows XP, it can take some time for that computer to appear in the Network window. You might need to move both computers to the same workgroup. You can do that by changing the workgroup on either computer. To change a workgroup, see [Join or create a workgroup](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/join-or-create-a-workgroup). You might also need to turn on file and printer sharing on the computer running Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

If you mount the PATA drive inside your new PC, you might be able to view the contents of the drive using a Recovery program such as `DiskGenius.` If you can view the contents you should be able to copy them across without trying to get ownership.

I'm not 100% sure on the ownership aspect, buy you should give `DiskGenius` a go and see what happens.

Comment: How can I use DiskGenius for this task? Do you care to explain? Also, do I need to pay the 69.95 USD license price before I can make any use of the program? Can I use the Trial/Demo version?

Comment: You can download the Trial Version or use it via Hiren's Boot CD. If you connect the drive to your new PC, DiskGenius may be able to view the directories within that drive even if the drive has no association with your new PC. Edit: You can get Hirens Boot CD from here: http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd

Comment: Is Hiren's Boot CD (HBCD) free software? How can that be when DiskGenius (DG) is shareware?... is it fully functional for 30 days or so? Do I have to boot from the HBCD to get access to DG?

Comment: Can you give me a short step-by-step on how to use DG for this purpose? Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't DG primarily a disk partitioning program (with addition of data recovery features)? What feature of DG would you want to use?

Comment: It is that, but it may help in viewing the contents of the drive if you can get it connected to your new PC. HBCD is free and all provided applications will run perfectly fine. Because the programs are running off Read Only memory I don't think the 30 day trial period applies. I've used HBCD for a while now, without any message prompting me to buy the full version of DiskGenius or any other program I've used.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the two computers directly to each other. You will need a crossover Ethernet cable for that, and both computers will need to have Ethernet ports. You connect one end of the cable to the Ethernet port of one of the computers and the other end to the other computer.

You then need to configure the network settings on both computers.